# how to make user control come to front of everything after button click on form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a game that shows different layouts (hardness, mechanism, style etc). To display those different layouts I use User controls, which are sent to the front if a button is clicked. I use `milline.BringToFront();` to send them to front. Visual Studio gave me an error that "name" doesn't exist in current context. After some digging in google i added `UCmilline milline = new UCmilline();` before my command. Now Visual Studio gives me 0 errors, but when I try to click button in my form, it won't bring that UC to front

I'm looking to bring my User control named "milline" to the front after button click. My code looks like this

```
    private void play(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UCmilline milline = new UCmilline();
        milline.BringToFront(); /*brings my uc forward, at the start form is in front of my Uc*/
        MessageBox.Show("tere"); /*to check if button is working */
    }
}
```

Do i need to add anything more to `UCmilline milline = new UCmilline();` for it to work or do i need to add something to my usercontrol code?

Comment: By front you mean as a new window or to your form?

Comment: `new UCmilline()` is a new instance of control. Which is not added to `Controls` collection of form. If there is an existing instance on the form, you should find it or if you are going to create a new instance and bring it to front, first you need to add it to `Controls` collection of for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Add `millinie` instance you created in the `play` event to a control for it to show in any given Form/Control.If you have another instance of `UCmilline` added in the design time you can just access it by typing it's name in any were within you class file and use BringToFront() method.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solutions to my problem

I was using always wrong name in my code, my Uc name was uCmilline1 not UCmilline or Ucmilline1
Quite embarrassed now cause have had this problem for a week and have spent somewhere between 5 and 8 hours to find solution for this